# The type org.andengine.entity.shape.IAreaShape cannot be resolved.

Tags: android, andengine, physics

All 
      I got below error in andEngine.

```
The type org.andengine.entity.shape.IAreaShape cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

When I use below code from [this tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-11.html).

```
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, levelObject, BodyType.StaticBody, FIXTURE_DEF).setUserData("platform1");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I experienced some issues with IShapeArea also. Maybe you haven't added Andengine properly as library. Are you using AndEngine OpenGl 2.0 (Master)?

Comment: No i have use AndEngine-GLES2-AnchorCenter and add AndEngine-GLES2-AnchorCenter.jar in build path.

Comment: In my case, the AndEngine (core) library wasn't on the build path of the Box2d extension after moving some things around. Once that was fixed, it worked itself out. If there is no IAreaShape class, I am not entirely sure how it found it in the AndEngine library, but w/e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no IAreaShape class in the GLES2-Anchor branch. You are probably mixing some older libraries. Try downloading sources again. Note that your PhysicsBox2D extension must be from GLES2-Anchor branch too. Also, you should not add any jars to buildpath. You should see only:

- Android X.Y.Z
- Android Dependencies

And add libraries in the "Android" part of your project configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You must get the source code from the correct branch:
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension/tree/GLES2-AnchorCenter

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, it was with the AE site, even though I selected the "anchor center" branch when I hit the download it didn't look any different.  I'm not sure what I did but finally I got the physics engine to respond with an ANCHOR CENTER zip version to download. I had no problem getting the ANDENGINE ANCHOR CENTER zip file just the physics engine.